# Why is my MySQL unique key failing?

Tags: mysql, unique-index

```
INSERT INTO `ree`.`media` 
(`CREATEDATE`, `FILETYPE`, `MIMETYPE`, `MLSNUMBER`, `MODIFYDATE`, `POSITION`, `URL`) VALUES 
('2011-12-27T15:00:16', 'PRIMARY PHOTO', 'image/jpeg', 5030011414, '2011-12-27T15:00:16', 1, 'http://image.realcomponline.com/photos.rps?PATH=PROPERTY/57FA/57FAA44C48854C/3QQGONGA03I7CN.jpg&g=100&sp=0&l=0&t=0&r=10000&b=10000&o=0&1cf=0&w=320&h=240'),
('2011-12-27T15:00:18', 'PRIMARY PHOTO', 'image/jpeg', 5030011507, '2011-12-27T15:00:18', 1, 'http://image.realcomponline.com/photos.rps?PATH=PROPERTY/6FC7/6FC7B6F88D8F45/3SQGONGA01RXH1.jpg&g=100&sp=0&l=0&t=0&r=10000&b=10000&o=0&1cf=0&w=320&h=240')
```

**Error:** *Duplicate entry '2147483647-1' for key 'uneek'*

It seems like my UNIQUE key of MLSNUMBER isn't parsing the entire number before differentiating the two inserts.

Both start with 5030011...

**Here is how I build my the key:**
*ADD UNIQUE  `uneek` (  `MLSNUMBER` ,  `POSITION` )*

Is there a way to build this key so it accepts the entire 10 digits instead of the first 7 digits?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have run out of range of int.
2147483647 = 2^31 - 1
You might change this int on that field to be e.g. 64bit:

```
ALTER TABLE media MODIFY COLUMN MLSNUMBER BIGINT NOT NULL;
(Modify unsigned and not null for your needs).
```

Comment: He doesn't have `AUTO_INCREMENT` or he isn't using it. He is explicitedly providing the values for this column.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you've defined the MLSNUMBER column as an Integer type, and the large values are getting truncated to the largest 32 bit signed value, which is 2147483647.

I verified this by attempting to add the value 5030011507 to an Int column, and it ended up storing the value 2147483647. That matches the number in your error message. I also received a warning when the value was truncated.

You can try changing the column type to BIGINT, which will allow values up to 9223372036854775807.